# Rails 3 / Javascript- Set width of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I hate to ask the same question that's on here several times but I'm struggling to bring it all together.

I'm doing something I think should be pretty simple with javascript. Each time a page loads, I need to find with width of an img. With that img width, I need to assign it to the width of the div. So far I've come up with:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var imgWidth = $("img").width();
  $function setWidth(imgWidth){
    $("#main").css("width":imgWidth);
    return false;
  });
});
```

For each page that loads, I want to assign with width of the img (only one on a page) to my imgWidth variable. I then pass that variable into a function to change the css of my div with an id of mmain to with imgWidth.

Basically, I'm stuck. I can't get anything to work and am having problems seeing why I can't get it to resize.

Anyway, appreciate the help. I'm on rails 3, using jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery it's

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#main").width($("img").first().width());
});
```

Here were your mistakes:

- You should call document ready
- `$("img")` retrieves an array of elements. So either take the first like I did or provide a precise matcher.
- You're badly defining a function you don't call
- You're badly passing value to css attribute: [Doc here](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change

```
$("#main").css("width":imgWidth);
```

to

```
$("#main").css("width",imgWidth);
```

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just floating the div? E.g.

```
div#picture {
float: left; 
}
```

This way the width of the div will adapt to the size of the image - no JS required.

HTH

Comment: position: absolute; will also achieve this.